# C# Float/Double Difference dependent on Platform

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, 32bit-64bit

I have some strange behaviour on Double/Float when it comes to x64 and x86 Platform in C#.

A simple Test is here:

```
float testVar= 50;
double test = 1/ testVar* 1e6; (1e6 is double)
test == 19999.9995529652 for x64 and test == 20000 for x86
```

however:

```
double test = 1 / 50f *1e6; (1e6 is double)
test == 19999.9995529652 for both platforms
```

I know, the calculation between x64 and x86 is not the same (FPU with extended calculation on x86 and SSE2 on x64), but what really hits me is that x64 and x86 **only behave differently when float testVar is assigned before it is calculated and directly calculated there is no difference.**

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: I don't **know**, but my first _guess_ would be some compiler optimization? Did you check IL code for differences?

Comment: @Fildor: Thanks for answering. In IL Code itself i could not find the reason. @ jason.kaisersmith: Thats a really good, a bit complicated :), explanation  for the differences between x64/ x86. But as i understood, it is not the explanation why there is a difference, when the value is assigned before.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith OP is aware of _that_ difference. OP is experiencing an unexpected difference that does not _seem_ to be related to it. Or maybe it is, but it's not so obvious? Anyway, if it is, it's more of _how_ that applies. So, I wouldn't consider this a dupe.